# Setting Card Elevation makes top view on the card invisible for card area in lollipop

Tags: android, android-cardview, android-elevation

I am getting an issue on android lollipop. I have a FrameLayout, in that layout I have a Cardview and at the top I have a RecyclerView. like

```
<framelayout>
   <cardview/>
   <recylerview/>
</framelayout>
```

whenever I set cardElevtion everything works fine in prelollipop devices. I can see recyclerview items clearly and can scroll them, but in lollipop I am facing an issue that is items can scroll but they scrolls at the backside of cardView. CardView appears as floating. I am unable to figure out what is the importance criteria for different layouts in android lollipop release.

here are the screenshots. 
with 0 cardElevetaion.
[image]

with n cardElevetion. 
[image]

Answer (score 0):

I could not get any proper solution to this but all I figured out that after release of lollipop version, Android always give priority to components having greater elevation. This is why **cardview** with **n elevation** is being shown top of its own child (recyclerview).

**here is a possible solution**

You can also give some elevation to the children components, which should be greater or equal to elevation of **cardview (or parent component)**